# jquery FancyBox "parent" argument not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I've tried to apply fancybox "parent" argument in the following way (as stated here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs):

```
$.fancybox.open({ 
  autoSize: false, 
  width: 300, 
  height: 500, 
  content: $("#is-edit-div"), 
  parent: '.is-panel-edit-profile'
});
```

but it is still added to the end of the body,

```
$.fancybox.open({ 
  autoSize: false, 
  width: 300, 
  height: 500, 
  content: $("#is-edit-div"), 
  parent: "form:first" 
});
```

not working also.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by editing the .js file of the fancybox.
I noted this issue to the fancybox developers and hopefully they will fix it in the future releases.

I will explain where you have to modify using the file
jquery.fancybox.js
of version 2.1.3

Go to line 1713, which looks like

```
this.overlay = $('<div class="fancybox-overlay"></div>').appendTo( 'body' );
```

This is in the section on Overlay helpers, more specific in the "create" public method.

Change this line to look like

```
this.overlay = $('<div class="fancybox-overlay"></div>').appendTo(F.coming.parent || 'body' );
```

For me, which I choose to add it in the form:first, this added a scroll bar to the overlay lightbox. You then need to change the CSS class .fancybox-overlay to have the attribute overflaw-y: hidden.

If you want to use the minified version
jquery.fancybox.pack.js
you can just pack/minify the long version from above.
Or just modify their packed version by
searching for the code

```
<div class="fancybox-overlay">
```

and instead of adding the code

```
F.coming.parent ||
```

add something like

```
b.coming.parent ||
```

Please note:
Write the value for the parent option as given in the current fancybox documentation
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({  
    parent: "form:first" // jQuery selector  
});
```

Do not use a syntax like I found on other sites
https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/283
where they write $('form:first')

So any of your above codes should work fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is no longer necissary in 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox 2 now has support for the `parent` argument (in 2.1.5 at least). See screenshot from Fancyapps below

---

[image: Screenshot from Fancybox 2 API docs]